# python avoiding globals I am stumped

Tags: python

I am having a tough time with this python code I am writing, it is a text game. I will get straight to my question. I have "main_data" and a class called "adventurer" that I have been passing around my program like this:

```
main_data, adventurer = some_function(main_data, adventurer)

def some_function(main_data, adventurer):
    some code,
    return(main_data, adventurer)
```

my problem is that every time I want to use main_data or adventurer I have to pass it to each function and then return it, and it is making my code ...ugly?

please help!!

Comment: Why do you not have a class for the game that contains the adventurer, the data you need, and all your functions?

Comment: You can use a class and make them instance attributes, but normally this is what you would do.

Comment: This is a code smell that `main_data` and `adventurer` are becoming "god classes". Time to refactor to split up that responsibility.

Comment: You could pass around a list `game_data` which contains `[main_data, adventurer]`. A more elegant option would probably be to store the main_data in the adventurer class or vice versa.

Comment: You guys are going over way over my head!! This is what my code looks like: func1 I have to pass both to it, func2 I have to pass and return both, func3 same thing, etc,

Answer (score 1):

You have a  class:

```
class Adventure:
    def __init__(self, adventurer):
        self.adventurer = adventurer
        # Other adventure data

    def some_function(self):
        ...

bob = ...  # The adventurer
a = Aventure(bob)
a.some_function()
```

Comment: so "main_data" by the way is a dictionary, and in it i have things like 'collect_input' = True, so I can flip it to true and false, but doing it this way, I have to pass around this "main_data" all the time, sorry should have been more clear...